# JSDOM is not getting updated

Tags: npm, jsdom

I'm trying to update jsdom version.

Currently package.json is showing that jsdom version is 11.12.0.

```
"jsdom":"^11.12.0",
```

According to jsdom's npm page, the latest version is 21.1.0.

When I try `npm i jsdom` , version number is not getting updated. What's the right way to update jsdom version?